# TI AM335x QT4.8.3 read CANbus

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, can-bus

Short story: I have TI AM335x armv7l processor development board which runs embedded linux 3.2.0. I would like to read data from the CAN-bus and visualize this. I have no idea on how to start with this.

Longer story:
So I have a TI AM335x development board from GOEMBED (http://goembed.com/index.php/Products/detail/tpid/25 simular to the beaglebone black). It uses an armv7l processor which runs linux 3.2.0.

I connected a CAN-module to the development board. This CAN-module sends every second the same CAN-message onto the CAN-bus.

By entering the following commands into the terminal I can visualize the CAN-messages.

```
ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000 triple-sampling on
ip link set can0 up
candump can0
```

At this point I can see the the ID and data of the CAN-message.

```
root@goembed:~# ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000 triple-sampling on
root@goembed:~# ip link set can0 up
root@goembed:~# candump can0
  can0  1FC0000F   [8]  F5 F8 F1 00 00 00 F2 F3
  can0  1FC0000F   [8]  F5 F8 F1 00 00 00 F2 F3
  can0  1FC0000F   [8]  F5 F8 F1 00 00 00 F2 F3
  can0  1FC0000F   [8]  F5 F8 F1 00 00 00 F2 F3
  can0  1FC0000F   [8]  F5 F8 F1 00 00 00 F2 F3
  can0  1FC0000F   [8]  F5 F8 F1 00 00 00 F2 F3
  can0  1FC0000F   [8]  F5 F8 F1 00 00 00 F2 F3
  can0  1FC0000F   [8]  F5 F8 F1 00 00 00 F2 F3
```

Now the big problem is, how can I get this data into a qt-application?
I would like to print the data of a message into a textbox.

Hopefully somebody can give me some hints on how to start with this, so I can learn out of it?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy solution.
So as I want to read all messages in my embedded system, I easily just can take the response of my QProcess.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(&proc3,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(dataReady()));
    QD << QDir::currentPath();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::dataReady()
{
    while(proc3.bytesAvailable()){
        QString in = proc3.readLine();
        QString out;


        QRegExp reg("  can([01])  ([0-9A-F]+)   \\[([0-9]+)\\]  ([0-9A-F]+) ([0-9A-F]+) ([0-9A-F]+) ([0-9A-F]+) ([0-9A-F]+) ([0-9A-F]+) ([0-9A-F]+) ([0-9A-F]+)");

        if(reg.indexIn(in)>=0){
            out = "from Can%1 Id:%2 amount bytes:%3 first byte:%4 second byte:%5 third byte:%6 fourth byte:%7 fifth byte:%8 sixth byte:%9 seventh byte:%10 eight byte:%11";
            out = out.arg(reg.cap(1)).arg(reg.cap(2)).arg(reg.cap(3)).arg(reg.cap(4)).arg(reg.cap(5)).arg(reg.cap(6)).arg(reg.cap(7)).arg(reg.cap(8)).arg(reg.cap(9)).arg(reg.cap(10)).arg(reg.cap(11));
        }else{
            out = "Error:" + in;
        }
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(out);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    QString cmd1 = "ip";
    QStringList opt1;
    QD;
    opt1 << "link"<< "set"<< "can0"<< "bitrate"<< "500000"<< "triple-sampling"<< "on";
    proc1.start(cmd1,opt1);

    QString cmd2 = "ip";
    QStringList opt2;
    QD;
    opt2 << "link"<< "set"<< "can0"<< "up";
    proc2.start(cmd2,opt2);

    QString cmd3 = "candump";
    QStringList opt3;
    QD;
    opt3 << "can0";
    proc3.start(cmd3,opt3);
}

void MainWindow::on_stopButton_clicked()
{
    QString cmd4 = "ip";
    QStringList opt4;
    QD;
    opt4 << "link"<< "set"<< "can0"<< "down";
    proc4.start(cmd4,opt4);
}
```

So at this point I can put the ID, amount of databytes and the databytes itself into variables. So play time can start!
I hope this helps other people. If people know improvements, let me know.
Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should build Qt 5.8 for your platform and use the QtSerialBus module. Otherwise, you're facing the boring task of backporting QtSerialBus to Qt 4. It won't be particularly hard.

Once you have access to the serial bus module, you can easily get notified in real time as CAN packets arrive, and then display them in any way you wish. E.g. you could accumulate them in a model, and display them in a `QTableView`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you give me an example on how to backport this? I don't see how I should start doing this.

Comment: @MertensToon alternatively you can just create your own class, that would use standard socket API as shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SocketCAN). But I would also take Qt 5.8.

Comment: @MertensToon Copy the code to a new library project, and start fixing compiler bugs...